9V DC Class 2 Power Supply. Polarity?
I've got a 9V DC power supply with the barrel connector cut off the end. I don't have a meter with me and don't know the polarity.
One of the 2 conductors is marked with a White Stripe.
Is this marking have a standard meaning? + OR -?

There is no standard. You oould connect an LED and a resistor to determine the polarity.

I checked my wall-wart box, and two different output voltage units had the stripe on the negative (one solid and one dashed).
Also, check to see if the insulation on one of the wires has small ribs or ridges running the length of the wire.  This is another indicator of the negative lead.
No guarantees.
Is the unit heavy or light?  Lightweight wall warts usually have a switching supply, meaning the output is regulated.  Older, heavier units are just a transformer, diode, and capacitor.  For these units, the output voltage with no load can be much higher than the rating.  I've seen "12 V" units make 18 V.  In your case, a standard red or green LED and a 1 K, 1/4 W resistor should work fine as a polarity indicator.
